# How to get next column by adding 3 into column name instead of default 1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel and adding formula `=sum(A1:A10)`.

Here it sums all column from a1 to a10 but I need to sum only a1, a4, a7 and a10.

Is there any rule I get all desired column?

Answer (score 1):

This is formula for you.

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW($A$1:$A$10),3)=1,$A$1:$A$10))
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

If you data goes another location on sheet, then use this formula.

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW($G$6:$G$15)-ROW($G$6)+1,3)=1,$G$6:$G$15))
```

[image: Screenshot-2]

Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after putting formula as it is array formula.

Comment: its correct, but now i have another problem relevant to this, i have to get value of c14 in d1,c52 in e1,c90 in f1 etc, how can i do that?

Comment: what should i do to achieve what i asked in comment, note i only needs text of column c14,c52,c90 into d1,e1,f1 respectivly.

Comment: Put thi formula to d1 cell and pull right. 

=INDIRECT("C"&SMALL(IF(MOD(ROW($C$1:$C$200),38)=14,ROW($C$1:$C$200)),COLUMN(D$1)-COLUMN($C$1)))

Comment: Problem may be coming from copy paste of formula. Copy from below or type full formula with patient. See below update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be coming from copy paste of formula. Copy from below or type full formula with patient.

```
  =INDIRECT("C"&SMALL(IF(MOD(ROW($C$1:$C$200),38)=14,ROW($C$1:$C$200)),COLUMN(D$1)-COLUMN($C$1)))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i need values written in field c14,c52 and c90 there may b any text instead of 14,52,90

Comment: This formula will return value. I putted same value of row so that I can understand result. You can check with any value or text.